# Refreshing javascript if statement inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to refresh an `if` statement inside a function but its giving me an error

> cannont read property of status

```
$.getJSON("<url>/clients.json", function(data) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].client +  "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);

        var refresh = function() {
            if (data[i].status == "up") {
                $('td', tr).css ('background-color', '#88d066');
            } else {
                $('td', tr).addClass("statusHOSTDOWN");
            };
        }; 
        setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
    }
});
```

JSON example:

```
[{
    "client": "client1",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "status": "up"
}, {
    "client": "client2",
    "ip": "127.0.0.2",
    "status": "up"
}]
```

What would be the best way to rerun the `if` statement and update table color with new information from JSON without running the whole function inside setTimeout. Because running the whole function inside `seTimeout` just appends more table at the bottom of the existing table without replacing it with new information.

Comment: What about this ,($.getJSON("<url>/clients.json") html tag

Comment: By the time the refresh function is called, `i` will be `data.length` - and therefore `data[i]` is undefined

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking here. Why can't you do away with the `setTimeout`, and have everything executed inside the loop directly? Regardless, the error you're probably getting is "cannot read property status of undefined", because your `[i]` inside the setTimeout handler will be `data.length`, because of [the closure-problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: update with JSON format.

Comment: Concept of your code is wrong, I cannot conclude what you want to do. Defining functions within a loop is generally not acceptable, neither is using the loop's iterator in a time delayed function calls.

Comment: Maybe refactor the code into three functions: trExists(), updateTr(), insertTr().

Then the callback can iterate over each item in data, (psuedo-code)... if trExists(client) then updateTr(client, status) else insertTr(client, status).

Also maybe use class names like 'status-up' and 'status-down' and use jQuery to switch between the two using the value of data[i].status. E.g. `$(tr).removeClass('status-up status-host-down').addClass('status-' + status)`

Answer (score 0):

First make sure by debugging you 'data' parameter indeed has a property status, if so, Extract the value of the data[i] to a variable before the function var refresh is declared.

```
var myDataStatus = data[i].status;
var refresh = function() {...
```

And inside the if refer to the "up" directly from myDataStatus.

Answer (score -2):

Can you please try this code :

```
function refresh(statusVal, trObj){
    if(statusVal == "up")
    {
        $('td',trObj).css ('background-color', '#88d066');
    } else {
        $('td',trObj).addClass("statusHOSTDOWN");
    };
}

$.getJSON("<url>/clients.json",
function (data) {

    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].client +  "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    setTimeout(function(){refresh(data[i].status, tr);}, 5000);
    }

});
```

Comment: getting `Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`.

Comment: Can you please check is data have property status in it.. Please write the console.log(data[i]) in for lop. And then check in console what it is printing

Comment: This won't solve the closure problem. You instead need something like `setTimeout(refresh(i, tr), 5000);` and `function refresh(statusVal, trObj) { 
 return function () { 
  if(statusVal == "up") {
         $('td',trObj).css ('background-color', '#88d066');
     } else {
         $('td',trObj).addClass("statusHOSTDOWN");
     }; 
    };
}`. See https://jsfiddle.net/u9t2wdt2/ vs https://jsfiddle.net/u9t2wdt2/1/.

Comment: @robinbansalsolutions from cosole.log I am getting out of jason data as: `Object {client: "clientname", ip: "<ipaddress>", status: "up"}`

Comment: @Matt I tried your example, while it didn't give any error, it didn't also give any output. `console.log(data[i].status);` didn't return anything. I assigned data variable as `var data = $.getJSON("<url>/clients.json");`

Comment: @bran: That will not work because the `$.getJSON` request completes asynchronously. You need something like https://jsfiddle.net/u9t2wdt2/2/ to solve your closure problem; but this does not solve your question "*What would be the best way to rerun the if statement and update table color with new information from JSON without running the whole function inside setTimeout*", for which we need you to update your question to be more clear on.